Powershell Create ScheduledTask
I am trying to create a PS script that will run at a specific time/date.  I can get it to create the scheduled task with al of the settings I want but the task never kicks off.  If I check Task Scheduler, the "Next Run Time" is always blank even though the trigger is set up correctly.  If i manually create the task (via GUI, not using PowerShell). with all the same exact settings, it works fine - there is a date/time in "Next Run Time" and it kicks off.  What am i missing in my script or what is causing this behavior?  I can line up the one I create via PS and the one I create via GUI and every setting/option is exactly the same but only the one done via GUI has a Next Run Time and actually runs at the scheduled trigger time.  Any Insight would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!
Below is my code and a screen shot of the task scheduler:
$PSexe = "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
$actions = (New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute $PSexe -Argument "-File c:\Auto\outputtest.ps1")
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At '12:47:00 AM'
$principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId 'MyDomain\MyUserID' -RunLevel Highest
$task = New-ScheduledTask -Action $actions -Principal $principal -Trigger $trigger -Settings $settings 

Register-ScheduledTask 'PSSchedTest' -InputObject $task



